# Drupal url to teaser overview page

Tags: drupal, programmatically-created, teaser

It's probably the most simple question, but what is the url to the teaser overview page?

I'd make a content type 'X' and did make a template for the teaser and for the fullpage like this:

```
    <?php if ($teaser) { ?>

     <!--Teaser-->

    <?php 
    } else { ?>

     <!--Full page-->

    <?php } ?>
```

Now, my question is: how to access the page with all teasers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box Drupal only has a front page where new content shows up.  This is where teasers would show up initially.

Usually you would create new pages or sections of pages using either taxonomy, views or custom page callbacks.

If you want all content types to show up on a page, the easiest thing to do would be to use views to create a new page that shows only nodes of that content type in teaser view.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'm going to use views. I do not prefer it because of all the extra html tags they create.